# Image height and width - How can I lock in one without changing the other?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I seem to be having some issues with an image. It's not sticking to the same width when I modify the max height, like below.

```
.lead-pic img {
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: -150px;
  max-height: 1000px;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is an image that covers both sides of the page and also reduce the height of the image at the same time. I'm not sure if there is some code that locks the width in place when you change the height pixels.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean when I change the height:
[image: Image is no longer full width]

This is on wordpress within a staging environment so I can't provide a URL to the website. Any ideas?

Comment: Images have an intrinsic height. If you want a different one, then you must specify it - so at least `height: auto` is also needed, if you want the actual width of the image to influence its height accordingly while respecting the aspect ratio.

Comment: `img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 1):

you can set only one property to image either `height` or `width`. If you set both the image will blur, aspect ratio is not same as original image. Try to wrap image in one element set property to that wraping element and assign `max-width: 100%;` to image tag.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong on this one, if you use the `background-size` property it will not be aplied to your image which is coded in your HTML file. For this you need to ad a `background: url(link/to/image.png)`

```
.lead-pic {
  background: url(link/to/image.png);
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: -150px;
  max-height: 1000px;
```

Example:

```css
.lead-pic {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class=lead-pic></div>
```

Hope this helps. And, correct me if I'm wrong :).

Comment: This is interesting and could be what I'm after. However, when I apply this code using the following:

    .lead-pic {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 2050px;
    background: url(http://www.cutepinkboutique.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/pexels-photo-220436-1.jpeg) center top / cover;
    background-position: center top;
}

Its still not covering the full width. I'm also finding that its overlapping some of the other upper elements. How can this be stopped?

http://imgur.com/a/SZebl for screenshot.

Comment: I understand why its overlapping. Its because its being recognised as a background rather than just an image. Know a way to modify a background images position?

Comment: It is the div with the background url within it. In the example it is the div with the class ´.lead-pic´. You can position that ´div´ wherever you want, and what ever size you want

Comment: Yes I understand that but what I'm finding is that when I use it as a background image, its going above the content above it. I'm trying to move it using .lead-pic but it just stays there overlapping. Have a look here: http://imgur.com/a/EXwUM. I used your exact code.

Comment: Never mind, encased it in another element and added padding: 120px

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a background and to automatically adjust size, try making the image position fixed and putting your content in div with position:absolute.  Use vh and vw to set the size.  vh and vw are percentages of the current viewport height (vh) or width (vw).

i.e.:  height:100vh = 100% of the current viewport height.

```css
.lead-pic {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content-example {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<img class="lead-pic" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/d7/ab/7fd7ab72321777f4413ae3485622896c.jpg" />

<div class="content-example">
  All of your content can go here.
</div>
```

Keep in mind that this will stretch the image disregarding the aspect ratio and will degrade the quality.  If you want to keep the quality of the image, set it to 100vh/vw in the direction of the shortest dimension (in this case, width:100vw).  The following snippet expands the image width, only:

**ADDED AFTER CORRESPONDENCE, BELOW**
This will get you the div like I understand you want it.  If you want to add parallax functionality, I'd suggest searching for "Pure CSS parallax"

```css
.lead-pic-container
{
max-height:200px;
height:200px;
width:100vw;
overflow:none;
background-size:cover;
background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/d7/ab/7fd7ab72321777f4413ae3485622896c.jpg');
background-position: 50% -325.828px;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>

<div class="lead-pic-container"></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Hi Lee thanks for this. Image quality is a big thing for ecommerce so I can't use it. I noticed in your example that it didn't stretch all the way. Maybe it was just my screen?

Comment: I just used the image from the screenshot that you gave.   That image includes white space so it appears to not stretch.  If you try this with the original image, it will cover the entire page.

Comment: I've edited the example to use another image.  You can see the results, above.  The second snippet is the one I'd use.

Comment: You could use a @media rule in CSS to determine which way to stretch it.

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your suggestion. I gave this a go and found that the image took up all the content on the page and overlapped. When i scrolled down, the position was fixed, as per the CSS. I'm going to have a play around with the code and see I can get it to work the way I want it. In a nutshell, our live site: cutepinkboutique.com has a parallax hero that I'm looking to implement on our staging (new and improved). The way it stays consistent between width and height is what I'm looking to achieve with staging. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for your reply.  Are you trying to get an image to behave like the large one at the top of the landing page of that site(cutepinkboutique.com)?

Comment: Yes thats right, the one with the green button in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

With combined information from stack overflow users, here is the answer:

```
.lead-pic {
  background-image: url(http://www.cutepinkboutique.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/pexels-photo-220436-1.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
  width: 2000px;
  margin-left: -220px;
  background-position: 50% center;
}

.move-pic {
  padding: 120px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```